# jmeter, simulate users with lower number of threads

Tags: java, performance, testing, web-applications, jmeter

I am looking for a way to simulate more concurrent users of a web application than I use real threads in jmeter. I want to simulate close to real-world usage pattern, i.e.
user periodically does something on the page but stays logged in 9 hours a day, then logs out. Users in other areas do same at different times, etc. I want to potentially simulate 100000 or even more users of the system. So it makes a big difference if I can use less threads than simulated users. I'll be perhaps using whatever number of amazon ec2 large instances it takes.
I can't see any indication that this is possible with jmeter. I guess it is if I write my own sampler and use my own thread pool and save state of each logged in user to some cache but that removes a lot of benefits using the framework.

In a [mailing list thread](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/number-of-threads-vs-number-of-simulated-users-td2258255.html) I'm reading some rational but it boils down to being too hard to implement and not worth. Well I think the only real way to test a web app is to simulate the anticipated real usage pattern which means a lot of idle users.
So I'm wondering if I'm missing some way to do that or does just nobody care enough to implement?

Comment: Why would a [throughput shaping timer](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer) not suffice ? You don't have to run a test for 24 hours to find a weakness in the app. If the app can take peak load, it can handle light load.

Comment: Sorry, but how 'idle' users affect performance? A very specific case, when application store a lot of data in session and session lasts a long time, can be checked in different way, without simulation 100000 users all time.

Comment: @deepak-bala, that's a good plug-in, but I have a goal set to achieve a particular setup to handle N total system users. Stressing an app for extended periods of time is also mandatory for its quality. @ user1516873, yeah, I can do all kinds of workarounds, but it is best when one can simulate what is actually anticipated as a usage pattern. It's so much simpler and much less error prone. btw I'm not sure why do I defend myself for trying to simulate usage as it is going to happen instead of doing synthetic type tests as a workaround.

Comment: @akostadinov JMeter doesn't suit you in that case. If you _can_ write non-synthetic tests and it looks simpler than synthetic for you, writing your own tool for running that kind of tests will be easy enough.

Comment: @pmd-ubik-ingenierie, that's real cool. It is not impossible to simulate more users than threads but it's useful anyways. btw good that there is google translator :)

Comment: I your use case, I see no reason to reduce the tread maximum count. It don't slow down your JMeter. With different/own implementation you also hold the data for your simulated users, you will also consume nearly the same amount of memory.

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have to have 1 thread per user? Couln't a single thread iterate over a set of users?

Comment: @PålOliver, that was exactly my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try building your own JMeter Cloud using docker & any cloud provider (a lightweight virtualisation). Check my presentation here - http://goo.gl/fJByCb